# How to add new dict key:value pairs to a panda DF?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to scrape some information from a website through a JSON file hosted on the cloud.

1. Scrape JSON hosted on a website
2. Find out what's the new key:value pair
3. Append the values to a dictionary
4. Turn the dictionary into a pandas DF

I have been able compare the new JSON file against the old one and determine what is new.

```
import json
new_file = open('Fruit_new.json')
new_json = json.load(new_file)

old_file = open('Fruits_old.json')
old_json = json.load(old_file)

x = {}

for i in new_json['fruits']:
    if i not in old_json['fruits']:
         print(i)
```

Output:

```
{"name": "Grapes","colour": "Purple"}
{"name": "Watermelon","colour": "Green"}
```

I want to move the output to a pandas DF, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about it. My understanding is I have to somehow turn the output into a dictionary first.

Ultimately, I want the output to look like:

```
name        colour
Grapes      Purple
Watermelon  Green
```

Once I have the DF, then it will be much easier to write it on Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','colour'])
for dict_ in your_dicts:
    df = df.append(dict_, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CplMang I'm glad that it helped! Please accept the answer so that others would know this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dictionary, you can initialise a DataFrame with it directly.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = [{"name": "Grapes","colour": "Purple"},
     {"name": "Watermelon","colour": "Green"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
print(df)

         name  colour
0      Grapes  Purple
1  Watermelon   Green
```